# Precise rotation around world axis using Tween

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, rotation, tween.js

I have been trying to rotate a cube around world axis for a while,but it is not giving accurate results.Answer to my last question [Rotate object around world axis with tween.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097101/rotate-object-around-world-axis-with-tween-js) helped me get the rotation done but not as I was expecting.I am using

```
var cubeAngle = 0;
var start = {angle: cubeAngle};
var end = {angle: cubeAngle + 90};
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(start)
  .to(end, 300)
  .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
  .onUpdate(function(){
   cubeAngle=this.angle;    
   rotateAroundWorldAxis(cube[1], new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0),degreeToRadians(cubeAngle));
   })
  .start()
```

to rotate it but somehow it is not getting the right angles.What i found is that instead of adding 90 to cubeAngle in full 300 milliseconds,it is adding 90 to cubeAngle every milliseconds for a duration of 300 milliseconds and so it rotates a lot more than I need it to.

After some hit and try I found a match of small value to add to cubeAngle and time to rotate it 90 degrees but every time I reloads the page and click to rotate(as I am using on click event) it rotates differently by few degrees.

I have some [screenshots](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-A8PSYZEySfUml1Ri14aFg0Mk0&usp=sharing) to show this.Sometimes the difference is small but sometimes it's too noticeable and as I need multiple rotations so at the end it variate to much.So,what is causing this and how to do this the right way to get accurate result?Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,is true, you add the rotation twice...

you count "n" from 0 to 90, but in every loop you rotate by n, so the result is:

1° n=0 rotation=0

2° n=1 rotation=0+n = 1

3° n=2 rotation=1+n = 3

4° n=3 rotation=3+n = 6

5° n=4 rotation=6+n = 10

...

for solve your problem you have to rotate by delta from the previous rotation.

```
var cubeAngle = 0;
var start = {angle: cubeAngle};
var end = {angle: cubeAngle + 90};
var lastAngle=0;                                // global var
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(start)
  .to(end, 300)
  .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
  .onUpdate(function(){
      cubeAngle=this.angle;    
      //rotate only delta
      rotateAroundWorldAxis(cube[1], new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0),degreeToRadians(cubeAngle-lastAngle));
      lastAngle=cubeAngle;                     //save last position
   })
  .start()
```

Comment: Amazing,Exactly what I wanted thanx again for your help!!